# How to sanitize an object on create in Rails 2.3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, sanitize, oncreate

In my search I mainly found ways to sanitize data when outputting OR sanitizing single input boxes using:

```
<%=h @name %> OR ['name = ?', params[:name]]
```

However, I'm creating an object like so:

```
@user = User.new( params[:user] )
```

Now, I could sanitize each key in the params[:user] hash one by one, but I'm sure there is a more elegant technique.

Comment: `h` takes care of HTML, which shouldn't matter to you when you e.g. insert content into a DB. In this case you should rather worry about things like SQL injection, which Rails as well prevents, if you're using the AR (correctly). —In this sense, I don't think you'll find an elegant/Rails–y way to do what you're looking for, since it is not commonly done.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused... if Rails already takes care of SQL injection, then which scenarios is this: ['name = ?', params[:name]] used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for optimization reasons, use the '[Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/)' gem.  However, since you talk about doing it for every single field, something smells a little wrong here.  ActiveRecord already escapes input to avoid SQL injection problems, but you shouldn't need to HTML-escape every single thing that goes into your database (and doing so could cause issues later down the line if you want to process the original data in some way).  The only things you may want to sanitize before they go into the database, for performance reasons, are things like Rich Text Editor input fields, such as data coming from TinyMCE, where you actually want to filter the data against a white-list, not just escape it with simple string conversions.